# GPS is not launching at first run after clicking "OK"

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location

GPS is not launching at first run after clicking "OK" of  "**Would like to use your current location**" message. I have a table view to display the places' names around current location. There is no map view in the table, just employs CoreLocation framework. When i first build and run my app and get in the table view, the famous message "**"myApp" Would like to use your current location**" jumps out. After the "OK" button is clicked, the GPS is not running. But when I get in the table view again, the GPS works well.

**Question is**: how could i make the GPS run at the first launch after the "OK" button is clicked? Thanks in advance!

Edit 1

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];    

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];    
}
```

Is there anyway to detect that the  "OK" button of "**Would like to use your current location**" message is clicked?

Comment: After you repopulate the table with the locations nearby, did you redraw the table? What table methods are you using to update the rows?

Comment: @JasonKulatunga Actually the GPS indicator on the status bar is not launching for the first run after the "OK" button is clicked.

Comment: when do you call `startUpdatingLocation`?

Comment: @HolgerFrohloff in 'viewDidAppear'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

show you some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

         [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self     selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer{

if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        [self startUpdatingCurrentLocation];
        [theTimer invalidate];
    } 
    [self startUpdatingCurrentLocation];

}
```

A timer waits until a certain time interval has elapsed and then fires, sending a specified message to a target object. [NSTimer Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

A timer can perform starting GPS for a second time and in a transparent way if user pressed "ok" button. If not, the timer will keep checking the GPS staus until app gets user's choice.